# Is there any way to override the send method of NESTJS ClientTCP?

Tags: tcp, microservices, nestjs, transport

What I am trying to do is to have a client sending some extra data to the server via TCP call in NESTJS, but do not want to modify all the callers of the original send() method. So, was wondering if there is anyway easy of overriding the send() method from ClientProxy instead of implementing the ClientProxy myself?

By reading the nestjs doc, I see a possible way is to implement my own ClientTCP, but can I still use the ClientProxyFactory, looks like have to implement the whole module then.

Comment: What about using a custom proxy class, [as described in the docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport#message-serialization)?

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel, thanks for response, already resolved by creating my own ClientTCP. Instead of using the ClientProxyFactory I initialise the customised client by new. I thought I have to handle the other ClientProxies, but turn out that my use case is just TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was resolved by creating my own ClientTCP. Instead of using the ClientProxyFactory I initialise the customised client by new. I thought I have to handle the other ClientProxies, but turn out that my use case is just TCP.

Referenced to doc: https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport#custom-transporters